# Spotify API refresh token

Tags: python, spotify

I am trying to use Spotify's API to get song details. My programming language is python and the code I am trying to execute is this:

```
def spotifysearch(searchterm):
  headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer OAUTH TOKEN',
}
  params = (
    ('q', searchterm),
    ('type', 'track'),
    ('limit', '10'),
)
  
  response = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', headers=headers, params=params)
  a=response.json()
  return a
```

However, my OAUTH TOKEN expires after every hour and I can't just manually get a new token every hour. I couldn't understand how to get my refresh token automatically.

Please provide me answer in either python or on curl (Both are fine with me)

Comment: Maybe this answer can help - [Spotify Refresh Token Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67300645)

Comment: So, are you fine with EM28 answer or searching for something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step will be to record:

- when you got the token
- when the token will expire

You can use dataclasses for this. Dataclasses have a post_init func, which is executed
after initialization. You should compute the expiry as a datetime there.

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class TToken:
    access_token: str
    refresh_token: str
    created: datetime.datetime
    expires: datetime.datetime

    def __init_post__(self, data):
        if data: # Not required
            self.access_token = data['access_token']
            self.created = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            self.expires = self.created + datetime.timedelta(minutes=59)
            self.refresh_token = data['refresh_token']
    
    def is_expired(self):
        return datetime.datetime.utcnow() > self.expires

    def as_header(self):
        return {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': f'Bearer self.access_token',
        }
```

For your tokens.

```
BASE64_CID_CSEC = <base64 encoded clientid:clientsecret>

def token_get(authorization_code: str):
    data = {'form':{'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': authorization_code,
            'redirect_uri': <your redirect uri>},
            'header':{'Authorization': f'Basic {BASE64_CID_CSEC}'}}

    resp = requests.get('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', data=data['form'], headers=data['header'])
    return TToken(resp)

def token_refresh(refresh_token: str):
    data = {'form': {'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'refresh_token': refresh_token},
            'header': {'Authorization': f'Basic {BASE64_CID_CSEC}'}}

    resp = requests.get('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', data=data['form'], headers=data['header'])
    return TToken(resp)
```

Finally

```
token = token_get(authorization_code)

def spotify_search(searchterm: str):
    if token.is_expired():
        token = token_refresh(token.refresh_token)
    
    params = (('q', searchterm),('type', 'track'),('limit', '10'))
  
    resp = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', headers=token.as_header(), params=params)
    return resp.json()
```

Comment: Probably the trickiest part for the op problem was the `token_get` function to work with refresh token

Comment: @kosciej16 I'm running into the same problem as you, what I'm trying to do is, starting from the streaming history, get the features of the songs such as tempo, loudness etc ... can you give me some advice?